# confusion about weak topologies

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, weak-convergence

In C*-Algebras and Operator Theory by Murphy, it is stated in Chapter 4.2 that on a norm-bounded closed set, the ultra-weak topology and (relative) weak topology coincide. However, it later asks in an exercise to prove that a weakly convergent sequence of operators is necessarily norm-bounded. Doesn't this imply that any weakly convergent sequence is ultra-weakly convergent?

Namely, if $(u_k)$ is a weakly convergent sequence(to say $u$), then it is contained a closed ball of radius $r$. But then on this closed ball, $(u_k)$ is ultra-weakly convergent to the same limit $u$.

But there is clearly something wrong here as ultra-weak topology and weak topology do not necessarily coincide but I am not sure why. I would like to see where it goes wrong in this reasoning as we have an apparent contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re right that any weakly convergent *sequence* is ultraweakly convergent to the same limit. But this does not hold if you replace *sequence* by *net*. In infinite dimensions neither of these topologies is second countable, so you can’t just use convergence of sequences to characterize these topologies.

Comment: okay, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a simple way to see that ultra-weak and weak topologies do not coincide in general?

Comment: @Alg-top The simplest way to me is just to observe that the collection of continuous linear functionals for the two topologies are different. The functionals continuous under the weak topology are represented by finite rank operators while for the ultraweak topology they are represented by all trace class operators.

Comment: @Alg-top Though if you want an explicit example of a net converging weakly but not ultraweakly, I believe the following would do: consider the net $(H_0, n)$ where $H_0$ are finite dimensional subspaces of $H$ and $n$ are positive integers. Then let $x_{(H_0, n)} = np_{H_0^\perp}$. This net should converge to 0 weakly but does not converge ultraweakly. (Assuming your Hilbert space is infinite dimensional.)

Comment: what do you mean by a collection of continuous functionals? I am assuming not $B(H)^*$. What do you mean also by _represented_  by finite rank operators? I understand for example that every element of $B(H)$ can be represented as an element of the dual space of trace class operators.

Comment: @Alg-top For the first question, I meant those linear functionals in $B(H)^*$ that are continuous with respect to the specified topologies (weak or ultraweak). By “represented by”, I meant the pairing given by the trace.

Comment: @Alg-top For any trace class operator $T$, $S \mapsto \mathrm{Tr}(TS)$ is a linear functional on $B(H)$. All such linear functionals are ultraweakly continuous and in fact any ultraweakly continuous linear functional corresponds uniquely to such a trace class $T$. But such a linear functional is weakly continuous if and only if $T$ is of finite rank.